# How I can fragment a big node of a list to some smaller nodes of another list?

Tags: java

I have this number in a linkedlist node. it is 27 digits: 980089673400089200098129823

I need a method to fragment it  such below in a new list (every 4 digit in a node) :

27 ->9800 ->8967 -> 3400-> 0892 -> 0009 -> 8129 -> 823

Comment: This seems simple. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

1) Convert the number into a string.

2) divide the length of the string by 4. ( don't hardcode 4, configure it)

3) Find that many subset strings and insert them into the new list.

Pretty simple, i hope you weren't looking for someone to code it for you.
Hope it helps.

```
String str = String.valueOf(<your integer>);
int strLength = str.length();
int subStrCount = strLength/4;
List newList = new LinkedList();
for(int i=0;i<subStrCount;i++){
newList.add(str.subsctring(i*0, (i+1)*4));
}
newList.add(subStrCount*4, strLength);
```

Comment: cau you send me a sample of fragmenting ?  my Problem is "Find that many subset strings and insert them into the new list"

Comment: I have added a snippet which should give the idea; I am answering this on my phone so the snippet might have compilation errors or bugs, so use a debugger and sort it.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i*4 < str.length(); i++) {

            if (((i * 4 + 4) >= str.length())) {
                System.out.println(str.substring(i * 4, 27));
            } else {
                System.out.println(str.substring(i * 4, i * 4 + 4));
            }
        }
```

If you need to convert to an int use:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = node.value();
int [] numbers = s.length%4 ? s.length/4 : s.length/4 + 1;
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseToInt(s.substring(i*4, 4));
}

return numbers;
```

numbers will contain all the digits